# Zoom Out Image Onload (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

How to zoom out image and always center using Jquery? First, I want just display certain part of image only. Refer to this image:

[image]

Certain part = image that have been focused (doesn't have white transparent background on it)

When zoom out, I want it always center. And want zoom out onload. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! :D

Using center background-position and margin + javascript. Here is completed code:

CSS

```
#zoom-box {
    background-image: url('test.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 3548px;
    height: 1653px;
    margin: -500px 0 0 -950px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#zoom-box').animate({
    width:'800px',
    height:'373px',
    margin: '0'
}, 5000);
```

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: grey; width: 800px; height: 373px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="zoom-box"></div>
</div>
```

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93Wxw/

Thanks so much to Iszuddin Ismail (kidino). :D